# What is the meaning of COMRESET failed?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, dmesg

Laptop's internal WD SATA HDD of 1 TB is not being detected from any OS. It does not have any physical damage.

However while booting to linux from another disk, log is printed

```
[    6.397803] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   11.101680] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   16.449538] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   21.153415] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   26.501275] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   56.180496] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   56.180568] ata5: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   61.192365] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   61.192435] ata5: reset failed, giving up
```

What does it mean ?

Does it mean HDD is taking too long to respond hence OS gives up ? If so, is it possible to configure OS to attempt several more times ?

Does it mean hard disk is damaged and no way to use it anymore? Please explain the relation to COMRESET failed error ?